# Eloquent Laravel : creating a counter with foreach loop

Tags: laravel, eloquent

using Laravel's Eloquent, I'm trying to add an incremental counter to certain rows based on their 'product_id'.

I thought I could do it like this :

```
$foos = GanttTask::where('product_id',1)->orderBy('date', 'ASC');

$counter = 1;

foreach($foos as $foo){
    $foo->custom_counter = $counter;
    $counter +=1;
}

return $foos->get();
```

But this is of no effect on my data, custom_counter column doesn't change (but I get no error).

I tried to add `$foo->save()` within my loop with no effect.

Comment: So I tried but with no effect in the database.
With this change,  `return $foos;` returns me an array with correct values.

Comment: Try your code with `foreach($foos as &$foo){`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get first all record and then modify single record using save method like this:

```
$foos = GanttTask::where('product_id',1)->orderBy('date', 'ASC')->get(); // Get All records

$counter = 1;
foreach($foos as $foo){
    $foo->custom_counter = $counter;
    $counter +=1;
    $foo->save(); // Update each record
}
```

Good Luck !!!

Answer (score 0):

To actually update the database, I reckon you need to persist each data object `foo` individually not the collection `foos` as a whole.

```
$foos = GanttTask::where('product_id',1)->orderBy('date', 'ASC');

$counter = 1;

foreach($foos as $foo){
    $foo->custom_counter = $counter;
    $counter +=1;
    $foo->save(); // Persisting data here
}
```

Comment: Still no effects on my table!